# What is the HTML<xxxx>Element type for <b> tag elements in the HTML DOM API?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to figure out what the element type is for `<b>` tag elements so I can test for them in a list of childNodes I'm iterating over.

From this documentation I can see the collection of the so called HTML DOM Interfaces, ie the `HTML<X>Element` classes, over at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API

This includes things like

- HTMLAnchorElement
- HTMLAreaElement
- HTMLAudioElement
- HTMLBaseElement
- HTMLBodyElement
- HTMLBRElement

There are 67 such element classes (with some inheritance going on I presume) but I can't make out which if any of them corresponds to the `<b>` tag. Is there such an element correspondence or they're catalogued under a generic element type with known property values or something?

---

grepping this list for any ocurrence of the letter `b` hits 13 elements none of which seems to make sense for a specific match.

```
$ grep -i b html_elements.txt 
HTMLBaseElement
HTMLBodyElement
HTMLBRElement
HTMLButtonElement
HTMLEmbedElement
HTMLLabelElement
HTMLObjectElement
HTMLTableCaptionElement
HTMLTableCellElement
HTMLTableColElement
HTMLTableElement
HTMLTableRowElement
HTMLTableSectionElement
```

[image: testing b tag elements against instance type]

Comment: Its just the generic [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). If you want to differentiate between elements you can look at the [tagName property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

Comment: _"Is there such an element correspondence or they're catalogued under a generic element type with known property values or something?"_ According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b, it's classified as just `HTMLElement`

Answer (score 4):

`document.createElement("b").constructor.name` will yield `"HTMLElement"`, where `document.createElement("form").constructor.name` would yield `"HTMLFormElement"` for instance.

As per the MDN docs and this little experiment, you can conclude that there is no specific type/interface for it like many other DOM nodes do.

Comment: That's a great technique to look up the constructor, didn't know about that one. So together with @j08691 it looks like that's the DOM API interface that matches it's just the generic`HTMLElement`. It looks like that is simply not differentiating enough since other tags share this interface eg `document.createElement("a") instanceof HTMLElement == true`. I gotta look at something more discriminating than instanceof checks then. Now I know.

Comment: `HTMLAnchorElement` extends from `HTMLElement`, which extends from `Element` which extends from `Node`, which extends from `EventTarget`

Comment: yah I figured there was inheritance going on, seems like an oversight during design to leave the `<b>` tag just at HTMLElement, but it is what it is. I may be thinking too deeply on it expecting each tag to be one to one in both directions against a class.

Comment: I think there's only a specialization if there's a need for specific properties or methods

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that. Just check the [`element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) or [`element.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) for `B`.

```js
document.querySelector("div").childNodes.forEach(function(el){
  console.log(el.tagName, el.nodeName);
  if (el.tagName === "B") {
    console.log("<B> was found!");
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  This is a <b>good</b> thing.
</div>
```